# How to position figcaption vertical right from figure?

Tags: html, css

I have a figure with a figcaption. I would like to position the figcaption beside the figure img, like the image below.

I already tried things like transform `rotate` and `origin`, but seems like the problem is that it not fit the new height/width of the parent object.

http://codepen.io/Caspert/pen/eWEvvL

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `position: relative` with `top:` and `left:` attributes valued to your `figcaption` class.

Note: The image and caption will always have to be the same size, etc. if you want consistent results. Also, there is nothing in place for screen resizing causing blocks to move around. You will need to address this for responsiveness, but this is the basic idea.

```css
figure {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

figcaption {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
   left: 280px;
   top: -102px;

/*   transform-origin: 100% 25px; */
}

figcaption p {
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/540x360" alt="Gear">
      <figcaption class="dash-holder vertical">
        <p>Gear</p>
      </figcaption>
      <!-- End figcaption.vertical -->
    </figure>
    <!-- End figure.col-md-6 -->
  </div>


</div>
```

http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/KmvWEx

Comment: Is there also a fix so I can align the text from the bottom as you can see in my design above?

Comment: I adjusted the codepen link at the bottom, basically added `margin-top` to the figcaption p element to move it into the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexbox for positioning and `transform-origin` to control rotated element. You can also modify position of `figcaption` starting from bottom of figure using margin [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1876/).

```css
figure {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
figcaption {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
figcaption p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="col-md-6">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/540x360" alt="Gear">
  <figcaption class="dash-holder vertical">
    <p>Gear</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```